# SQL query to retrieve data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have branch table , inventory table and item table. I want to  retrieve `item id`, `item name` , `qty` (quantity) and `branch name` (branch_add).

```
SELECT tbl_item.item_name , 
tbl_inventory. tbl_item_item_ID , tbl_inventory.qty , tbl_branch.branch_add
FROM tbl_item,tbl_inventory ,tbl_branch
WHERE (tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID) JOIN (tbl_branch.branch_ID=tbl_inventory`.tbl_branch_branch_ID)
```

That is the code which I have wrote but it gives bellow error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'join item_ID.tbl_item =
>   tbl_item_item_ID.tbl_inventory' at line 3

Could anyone please help me to solve this. And table will displayed on attached png.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
tbl_item.item_name,
tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID,
tbl_inventory.qty,
tbl_branch.branch_add
FROM
tbl_item,
tbl_inventory,
tbl_branch
WHERE
(
inner join tbl_item ON tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID
inner join branch_ID ON tbl_branch.branch_ID = tbl_inventory.tbl_branch_branch_ID
);
```

The above query gives syntax error.

Comment: Yes, it gives syntax error because it's not valid syntax. You cannot specify an `INNER JOIN` into a `WHERE` condition, like that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing `AND` between your `WHERE` conditions:

```
select 
    tbl_branch_branch_ID.tbl_inventory
    , item_name
from tbl_inventory
   , tbl_item
   , tbl_branch
where 
    branch_ID.tbl_branch=tbl_branch_branch_ID.tbl_i
    and item_ID.tbl_item = tbl_item_item_ID.tbl_inventory;
```

Also, your JOIN conditions are a little bit off.

I think this is the query you're **actually looking for**:

```
select
    t_inv.*
   , t_itm.item_name
from tbl_inventory t_inv
    inner join tbl_item t_itm on t_inv.t_item_item_id = t_itm.item_id
    inner join tbl_branch t_br on t_br.branch_id = t_inv.tbl_branch_branch_id
```

Using explicit JOINs is much better and clearer for reading the code and also can result in improved code performance.

Comment: change query like this: 
SELECT tbl_item.item_name , tbl_inventory. tbl_item_item_ID , tbl_inventory.qty , tbl_branch.branch_add
FROM tbl_item,tbl_inventory ,tbl_branch
WHERE(     
     inner join  tbl_item on tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID
     inner join branch_ID on tbl_branch.branch_ID=tbl_inventory`.tbl_branch_branch_ID)

But again 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join  tbl_item on tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID
     i' at line 4

Comment: @JananiGammanpilaArachchi Try the second query in my answer. It should give you what you want.